# How to persistently store Azure-quantum credentials

Tags: azure-quantum

I'd like to submit and retrieve many  Azure-quantum jobs with  python scripts executed  at the command line, without a Jupyter notebook.

The standard method to authenticate with Azure consists of the following sequence

```
from azure.quantum.qiskit import AzureQuantumProvider
provider = AzureQuantumProvider (
        resource_id = "/subscriptions/2…93c1/resourceGroups/AzureQuantum/providers/Microsoft.Quantum/Workspaces/xxx",
        location = "eastus"
    )
backend = provider.get_backend('ionq.qpu.aria-1')
```

The last command always triggers a unique authentication via local browser  `https://microsoft.com/devicelogin`
It takes a lot of clicking and the credentials are lost after script finishes.

Is there a way to persistently store those credentials locally to be reused by the subsequent call to azure-quantum service?

I'm looking for a solution  similar to IBMQ.load_account()  or MemoryCredentialStorage() working with QuantinuumAPI()
Thanks
Jan

Comment: Can you check if a [service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/optimization-authenticate-service-principal) works with `load_account()`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to not get prompted for credentials is to install the [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and login using `az login`; that will prompt once for credentials and then persist them locally in your machine so you don't have to sign in again.

Optionally, if you are using VS Code you can install the [Azure Account](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account) extension and sign in there.

For all these options, the code will automatically try to discover if you've used the CLI or the extension to log in and use that. It only defaults to prompt on the browser if it can't find anything else.

There are a couple of other options that you can use to provide the credentials, like environment variables or Managed Identity. They are documented at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it suffice I do once `az login`  and later Azure does not require another authentication.